# Cannot keep track of div position of treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have implemented a method of keeping track of Div positions - This works fine on my webpage.
Now I want to keep track of a div position on a `modalpopupextender` that contains a `TreeView` but its position is restored as 0.
I think it may be due to the fact that the popup has not rendered yet as the second message box (`alert(elem.scrollTop);`) below opens before the popup is displayed.

The first value being saved is alerted as 860 but is always restored as 0.
After the second alert the popup is displayed when I click OK which I believe is the problem as the page is not fully finished.

can you tell me please what i need to do to fix?

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Script to manage scroll position -->    
$(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);


    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {

        try {
            var elem = document.getElementById('AddFiles_Div');
            scrollTop = elem.scrollTop; 
            // I am working correctly   
            alert(elem.scrollTop);    
       }
       catch (err) {}
    }


    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        try {    
            var elem = document.getElementById('AddFiles_Div');
            elem.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            // I am always zero   .................. 
            alert(elem.scrollTop);     
        }

        catch (err) {}  
    }   

    });    

</script>
```

**C# Code that runs when a node is expanded .ie on Postback**

// Does some work and then runs the next lin.....

```
AddFilesModal.Show();
```

Comment: i added a line at the begining of endrequesthandler to show the popup and it works. but thats not what i need. the popup must be shown from the code behind

Comment: the problem is definitely related to the fact that the popup has not yet been displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this for a solution? - it works ok. i.e replace

```
$(document).ready(function () { });
```

with

```
function pageLoad() {}
```

Is this ok?

**Complete working Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Script to manage scroll position -->

function pageLoad() {

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);


    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {

        try {
            var elem = document.getElementById('AddFiles_Div');
            scrollTop = elem.scrollTop;
       }

        catch (err) {
        }

    }


    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        try {
            var elem = document.getElementById('AddFiles_Div');
            elem.scrollTop = scrollTop;

        }

        catch (err) {

        }
    }   

   //});
 }

</script>
```